# Error starting another activity

Tags: android

I am learning from android.com/training/basics. This is my myfirstapp.

here's my DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null)
                    .show();
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
    layout.addView(textView);
}
```

}

Now the error is:
    Error:(39, 67) error: cannot find symbol variable content

"content_display_message.xml"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.uttaran.project1.DisplayMessageActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_display_message">
    android:id="@+id/content">
</RelativeLayout>
```

"activity_message.display.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_display_message" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you should include your layout file, this is probably where the issue is (such as content not being defined or you named it differently?). Most R issues are due to errors in xmls.

Answer (score 2):

You code lacks closing `}` for the class (at the end of file)

**EDIT**

You got syntax error, (visible even with StackOverflow's syntax highlighting):

```
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_display_message">
android:id="@+id/content">
```

Remove `>` from `tools:showIn...` line.

Comment: Thanks. now I have    Error:(39, 67) error: cannot find symbol variable content    on the same line

Comment: Did you put whole file in your question? If so, you lack `import`'s